# Flutter/Dart row is not centering within the remaining space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to center a group of objects within a row using Flutter/Dart. I have tried various methods and all have failed. I want the icon to be to the left of the screen and the remaining variables (trips, followers, and following) to be centered in the remaining space. I have tried it a variety of ways using the MainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment classes based on some solutions I found on SO but none have worked. What am I doing wrong?

```
       Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.grey, // button color
              child: InkWell(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      size: 65.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              trips, followers, following,
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

**Image 1:** How it currently looks

[image]

**Image 2:** Flutter Inspector View

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot what it looks like? And some sample code to implement problem on my side.

Comment: I have added images of what I see but as for additional code there isn't much to add. The only other thing I have are the variables for trips, followers and following. Other than that it is a standard stateless widget. I tried to add a brief code snippet so that it was not overwhelmed with useless data.

Comment: You should apply center alignment to the column wrapping the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to evenly distribute the space right from the icon between the three texts, right?
I would solve this by wrapping the 3 widgets in another row for the rest of the space without the icon and then wrapp the Text in an expanded widget that fills the rest of the space.

i assume that trips, followers and following are columns.

```
Row(
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
 children: <Widget>[
  Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     ClipOval(
      ....(your stuff)
    )
   ]
  ),
    Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded(
           child: trips
        ),
       Expanded(
           child: followers
       ),
       Expanded(
           child: following
       ),
     ]
   )
 ]
) //Row End
```

In the Row documentation you can see how the expanded takes a third of the available space. [[1](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? I looked at the flutter documentation and I tried the method they used, but I am clearly doing something wrong because it did not work. I know it must be a simple mistake I just cant figure it out what I am doing wrong.